# How do we convert the minimum of two values into its actual result?

Tags: functions, matrix

I am writing a code in Mathematica where the entries of the matrix depends on the minimum function, which is a function of the position in the matrix. However, when I compile it, the entries appear as the minimum function instead of presenting the resulting value itself.

My question is: how do I convert the minimum entries into the result of such function indeed?

The code is given by:

`p[i_, j_, N_] := (1/N^i)*Product[Min[j + k, N], {k, 0, i - 1}]`

`P[i_, j_, N_] := p[i, j, N] - p[i, j - 1, N]`

`TM = Table[P[i, j, 3], {i, 1, 3}, {j, 1, 3}]`

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Please upload Mathematica code for a minimal example that can be copied, pasted and evaluated in our own notebook sessions. Thanks.

Comment: @Syed Thanks for the feedback! I have provided the code as suggested.

Comment: better not to use `N` for your variable, as this is a special letter in Mathematica. Can cause problems.

Comment: @Nasser Thanks for the suggestion, but it still does not work.

Comment: I actually do not understand your question. **where the entries of the matrix depends on the minimum function** I do not understand what this means. This is what your code gives me  ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWDEn.png)  it will be better to show an example of input and what the output you expect is supposed to be. sometimes an example explains things much better than just words can.

Comment: @Nasser That is exactly the result I want. I am totally new to Mathematica. How did you get the output for the Table?

Comment: **How did you get the output for the Table?** I just typed your code `p[i_, j_, n_] := (1/n^i)*Product[Min[j + k, n], {k, 0, i - 1}];
P[i_, j_, n_] := p[i, j, n] - p[i, j - 1, n];
Table[P[i, j, 3], {i, 1, 3}, {j, 1, 3}]`  after changing `N` to `n` as I suggested above, and you did you did that but it still did not work?  Make sure to start from clean kernel (type `Quit[]` in a cell above your input to clear everything before trying. You should get same result.  btw, not a good idea to use `p` and `P` in same code. They look the same on the screen. You can use different letters.

Comment: @Nasser What environment do you use to compile the code? How do you generate the output?

Comment: oh, I did not "compile" the code. I just run it as Mathematica code in the notebook. I assumed that is what you are doing. you do have mathematica, right? or are using the cloud or something like that? Can you show screen shot of what you are doing and the output you get?

Comment: I have mathematica. I just do not know how run the code as a whole. I tried to use shift+enter, but it does not work really well . . .

Comment: Just paste the code I showed inside one cell, then put the mose anywhere in the cell and hit the ENTER key on the number key pad. Not the RETURN key.  Or you can use SHIFT+RETURN.  But easier to just hit the ENTER key on right side of the key board (the one near the number pad). First time using Mathematica? This is very good code you wrote for first time!

Comment: @Nasser Thanks for the compliment as well as for the contribution.